# Does anyone see how I could shorten the following formula $\sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{i \neq j}^n (x_i-x_j) x_i\right)^2$?

Tags: summation, notation, closed-form, index-notation

Does anyone see how I could shorten the following formula

$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \left( \sum_{i \neq j}^n (x_i-x_j) x_i\right)^2$$

I'm hoping to get something involving the sum of squares formula.

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{align}
S_1&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
S_2&=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\\
T&=\sum\limits_{i<j} x_i x_j
\end{align}
Then
$$S_1^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2=S_2+2T$$ and
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_j) x_i\right)^2
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-x_j \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(S_2-x_j S_1 \right)^2\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n (S_2^2-2 S_1 S_2 x_j+ S_1^2x_j^2)\\
&= n S_2^2-2 S_1^2 S_2 +S_1^2 S_2\\
&= n S_2^2-S_1^2 S_2 \\
&= n S_2^2-(S_2+2T) S_2\\
&= (n-1) S_2^2-2T S_2
\end{align}